# Integer Overflow Query

Tags: java, integer, overflow

I've written the below program to for ATOI(String to Intger conversion). I'm trying to detect Integer Overflow error if my ongoing answer is going above or below it. 
But I'm getting the below error.

```
 public class Solution {
 public int myAtoi(String str) {
    int index = 0;
    boolean isPos = true;
    int temp = 0;
    int ans = 0;
    int present = 0;
    if(str==null || str.length()==0){
        return 0;
    }
    while(index<str.length() && (str.charAt(index)<48 || str.charAt(index)>57)){
        index++;
    }
    if(index-1>=0 && str.charAt(index-1)=='-'){
        isPos = false;
    }
    if(index<str.length()){
        ans = str.charAt(index++)-'0';
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
    while(index<str.length() && (str.charAt(index)>=48 && str.charAt(index)<=57)){
        present = str.charAt(index)-'0';
        temp = ans*10 + present;
        System.out.println("ans= "+ans + " temp= "+temp + " (temp-present)/10= "+ (temp-present)/10);
        if((temp-present)/10 != ans){
            ans = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            break;
        }
        ans = temp;
        index++;
    }
    if(!isPos){
        ans = -ans;
    }

    return ans;
 }
}
```

The output for the above is coming out to be:

```
 ans= 2 temp= 21 (temp-present)/10= 2
 ans= 21 temp= 214 (temp-present)/10= 21
 ans= 214 temp= 2147 (temp-present)/10= 214
 ans= 2147 temp= 21474 (temp-present)/10= 2147
 ans= 21474 temp= 214748 (temp-present)/10= 21474
 ans= 214748 temp= 2147483 (temp-present)/10= 214748
 ans= 2147483 temp= 21474836 (temp-present)/10= 2147483
 ans= 21474836 temp= 214748364 (temp-present)/10= 21474836
 ans= 214748364 temp= -2147483648 (temp-present)/10= 214748364
```

Could anyone tell me why my temp is going to be a negative number as expected but a calculation of (temp-present)/10 is giving me my previous ans? The idea is to check that the new overflowed value will not yield the old result if the operation is reversed.

If this is a wrong method to check for the overflow error, could anyone enlighten me of the right way to do it?

Comment: I suggest you use a long to calculate the value or you could check the value is less than Integer.MAX_VALUE/10 before doing *= 10. If equal you need an extra check.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to guard against overflow, use the "exact" methods of [`Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) (added in Java 8):

```java
// Old code
temp = ans*10 + present;
```

```java
// New code
try {
    temp = Math.addExact(Math.multiplyExact(ans, 10), present);
} catch (ArithmeticException e) {
    temp = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

Or, if you don't want to do that, since `present` is a number 0-9, the following test will suffice, since the only way for `temp` to be less than `ans`, is overflow to negative value:

```
if (temp < ans) // overflowed
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Integer class has a minimum value -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (inclusive)

The iteration after `temp= 214748364` is as follows

```
present = str.charAt(index)-'0'; // saves the integer 8
temp = ans*10 + present;         // 2147483640 + 8
```

To better understand, let's break it down
`2147483640 + 7 + 1` = `2147483647 (which is the max limit) + 1`.
This will cycle through the Integer range and thus get changed to `-2147483648`

To write a check to detect overflow, you can simply compare values of `ans` and `temp`.

```
if(ans > temp) {
  // there was an overflow
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that it has cycled through and has become -2147483648, a negative value. But what I'm asking is how when I reversed that operation with (temp-present)/10, it resulted in the correct previous ans which 214748364 when it should not? 
I'm reversing the operation on the negative number right? It should get me a wrong ans(which is what my check is), but it has given me the correct number which is why the check is failing.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Could you explain with a example where it should fail?